# Convert string of tab seperated data into list of objects in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, object, c#-4.0

I am facing hard time converting below string of input in C#. As you can see, the string of input are each in a new line seperated by \r\n. And each input data in one line is seperated by \t

I need to delete the lines which start with '!'

```
!710889\tF\t3400\r\n
BY\tF\t5000\r\n
G1\tC\t600\r\n
```

So Valid input file would be

```
BY\tF\t5000\r\n
G1\tC\t600\r\n
```

I need to convert this into following

```
Object {Info: Array[3]}
 > Info: Array[3]
 >[0]: Object
       id: 'BY'
       type: 'F'
       value: 3400
 >[1]: Object
       id: 'G1'
       type: 'C'
       value: 600
```

Following thing was tried but no success

```
 string[] values = str.Split("\t".ToCharArray());
 // ... do something with "values" ...
 xxx.aaa = values[0];
 xxx.bbb = values[1];
 xxx.ccc = values[2];
```

It didnt list all the elements as i wanted. Can someone please shed some light here

Comment: The code you have provided is too little to understand where the problem lies. Please add more context

Comment: Hi Steve, I updated the question. Does it make sense now. please let me know..

Comment: Hi @Ria desai, can you show the results you are getting?  What elements are there and what are missing?

Comment: @Trevor.Screws- the elements in the input shown above. I am not able to format it and convert it into a list of objects in C#

Comment: Have you tried splitting on the \r\n first to get each valid "object" and then go through each "object" and split on the \t to get the property values for them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take baby steps, and things get easier:

1. Get an enumeration of *lines* from the input string:

   ```
   var lines = input.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine },
                           StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
   ```
2. Filter out those you don't need:

   ```
   var validLines = lines.Where(s => !s.StartsWith('!'));
   ```
3. Split each valid line into your object fields and build a `ValueTuple` with the data:

   ```
   foreach (var line in validLines)
   {
       var fields = line.Split('\t');
       yield return ( fields[0],
                      fields[1],
                      int.Parse(fields[2]) };
   }
   ```

Note I've used C#7 native tuple support. If you are not using C#7, you'll have to change the code slightly. Anyway, putting everything together:

```
static IEnumerable<(string Id, string Type, int Value)>
    ParseData(string input)
{
    var lines = input.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine },
                            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var validLines = lines.Where(s => !s.StartsWith('!'));

    foreach (var line in validLines)
    {
        var fields = line.Split('\t');
        yield return ( fields[0],
                       fields[1],
                       int.Parse(fields[2]));
    }
}
```

I've obviously omitted any error checking or data validation. I'll leave that to you, but there are a lot of things that can go wrong in the code above: field count is not 3, parsing `field[2]` fails, etc.